# Microsoft Network Monitor 3.4 - how to disable DNS IP address resolving for Source and Destination columns?

Tags: networking, monitoring, ip, domain-name-system

I've downloaded Microsoft Network Monitor 3.4 and it appears that I can't disable IP address to hostname DNS resolution. Is there a way to disable the DNS resolution so i.e. I'd always see: 173.194.65.104 instead of google.com in the Destination column?

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to answer to myself as I've found the answer.

The DNS resolution can't be disabled in Tools: Options.

The solution: Capture (tab): Frame Summary (subwindow): Columns (button): Choose Columns: Destination Network Address (list entry). 'Destination Network Address' column displays unresolved IP address.